# Компиляторо-независимый экспорта класса из DLL на C++

Tags: c++, dll

Задумал создать DLL-библиотеку с OpenGL рендерером, да так, чтобы ее можно было потом использовать где угодно (ну почти). То есть, чтобы не было зависимости от версии компилятора и CRT, и достаточно было подключить .lib и .h файлы к своему проекту, и независимо от версии и конфигурации спокойно использовать. Слышал что такое невозможно провернуть если экспортировать классы обычным способом, и рекомендуется использовать C-интерфейс, экспортируя только функции. Но поскольку моя библиотека задумана ООП-шной, то все же захотелось найти способ эти самые классы как-то экспортировать. В итоге я наткнулся на так называемый "factory pattern", когда экспортируются методы создающий объект и возвращающие указатель на него. Казалось бы, проблема решилась, но возникли кое-какие вопросы. В той статье, где описывался данный подход ([это здесь](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/16/exporting-c-classes-from-a-dll)), предлагалось делать следующее:

- Создать базовый класс (класс А) с полностью виртуальными методами (и методом destroy, очищающим память)
- Создать класс-наследник (класс Б) от вышеупомянутого базового класса (А), где все виртуальные методы будут переопределяться
- Создать экспортируемый из DLL метод создания объекта, в котором, в динамической памяти (при помощи new) создается объект, но возвращается указатель на объект базового класса (я так понимаю, указатель cast'ится)

В итоге в коде у меня всё это выглядит как-то вот так:

Базовый класс (интерфейс):

```
#pragma once

#ifdef RENDERERGL_EXPORTS
#define RENDERERGL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define RENDERERGL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

/**
 * \brief Интерфейсный класс для рендерера
 */
class RendererGLInterface
{
public:
    virtual void destroy() = 0;
    virtual ~RendererGLInterface(){};
};
```

Класс наследник (основной класс, .h файл)

```
#pragma once
#include "RendererInterface.h"

/**
 * \brief Основной класс рендерера
 */
class RendererGL : RendererGLInterface
{
private:
public:
    /**
     * \brief Очистка памяти (вызов деструктора)
     */
    void destroy() override;

    /**
     * \brief Деструктор
     */
    ~RendererGL();
};

/**
 * \brief Экспортируемая функция создания рендерера
 * \return Указатель на объект рендерера
 */
extern "C" RENDERERGL_API RendererGLInterface* __cdecl CreateRenderer();
```

Класс наследник, реализация (.cpp файл)

```
#include "Include/RendererGL.h"

void RendererGL::destroy()
{
    delete this;
}

RendererGL::~RendererGL()
{
}

RendererGLInterface* CreateRenderer()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<RendererGLInterface*>(new RendererGL());
}
```

**Всё вроде бы хорошо, но..**

- В чем смысл отдельного класса-интерфейса (с виртуальными методами).
  Почему нельзя возвращать указатель не базового типа, а типа самого
  класса?
- Я правильно понимаю что метод destroy нужен поскольку удаление объекта класса должно происходить из DLL? Но насколько хорошо делать удаление самого себя через `delete this`? Будет ли более правильным создание экспортного метода вроде "freeA" который будет удалять объекты класс A?
- Может быть на данный момент уже есть какие-то более удобные способы экспорта? Могли бы стандартные умные указатели из STL как-то упростить жизнь (и как, если да)?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вообще-то такую бибилиотеку можно будет использовать только из программ, собранных тем же самым компилятором с несильно отличающимися настройками. "удобно", "упростить жизнь" - это не про C++...

Comment: Если у вас нет (либо их не нужно экспортировать) статических функций, то могу предложить использовать cmake - он достаточно умён, чтобы экспортировать все нестатические методы и функции из вашего кода. Он делает это по умолчанию для mingw, а для винды нужно задать параметр WINDOW_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой способ напрямую зависит от таблицы виртуальных функций и только в том случае если разные компиляторы строят такую таблицу одинаково можно говорить об использовании уже скомпилированной динамической библиотеки из испольняемого файла собранного другим компилятором. С условием, конечно, что на той же платформе, разрядности и т.п.

В целом используется абстрактный базовый класс, который называется интерфейсом и унаследованный от него класс, который называется реализацией. При этом реализация присутствует только в DLL, а интерфейсы используются в вызывающей программе. Порядок работы приблизительно следующий:

1. Вызывается функция DLL, которая создает объект в куче и возвращает
   указатель на него в программу.
2. Программа использует абстрактный класс (интерфейс) для работы с
   полученным указателем.

В конечном итоге, так как класс реализации унаследован от абстрактного будет использоваться полиморфизм и компилятор подставит значения из таблицы виртуальных функций при обращении через базовый абстрактный класс.

Интерфейс не должен содержать никаких методов кроме пустых, удобнее его делать структурой, а не классом. Все, что нужно скрыть можно скрыть в реализации.

```
struct RendererGLInterface
{
    virtual void destroy() = 0;
};
```

Ваша экспортируемая функция возвращает указатель на класс:

```
 RendererGLInterface* __cdecl CreateRenderer();
```

Функция С может вернуть только указатель на структуру или `void *`, но не на класс.
Универсальный вариант:

```
 void* __cdecl CreateRenderer();
```

Ну и отвечая на ваши вопросы:

> В чем смысл отдельного класса-интерфейса (с виртуальными методами).
>   Почему нельзя возвращать указатель не базового типа, а типа самого
>   класса?

Потому что при линковке не будет реализованных методов и программа в которой Вы хотите использовать объект из DLL просто не соберется.

> Я правильно понимаю что метод destroy нужен поскольку удаление объекта
>   класса должно происходить из DLL?

Да. Именно для этого.

> Но насколько хорошо делать удаление самого себя через delete this?

В этом нет ничего предосудительного, если Вы хотите, чтобы Ваш объект убрал за собой сам.

> Будет ли более правильным создание экспортного метода вроде "freeA"
>   который будет удалять объекты класс A?

Это будет просто по другому, но на самом деле, это добавляет функцию в DLL. А наличие метода внутри класса избавляет нас от этого. Помимо этого в С функцию придеться передавать пустой указатель и идентифицировать его внутри, чтобы правильно удалить, в  отличии от метода `destroy()` где объект о себе все знает. Ну, и если в будущем `CreateRenderer` будет создавать разные объекты, то и удаление проще делать через их метод.

> Может быть на данный момент уже есть какие-то более удобные способы
>   экспорта?

Вообще это уже далеко не новый способ работы с DLL он давно используется Microsoft для [COM объектов](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/introduction-to-com?view=vs-2019), и уже даже успел устареть. Можно [экпортировать сам класс](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/using-dllimport-and-dllexport-in-cpp-classes?view=vs-2019), как целиком так и отдельные методы, что в общем я бы и рекоммендовал использовать.